# Vue.js Parameterised variable names

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to parameterise variable names so they can be passed as properties into my component. In the example below I want to use this to pass the names of the item variables into the array so I can selectively display them as columns in a table without the binding having to know the item variable names.

```
<div id="myApp">
   <h2>parameterized variable names</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="label in labels">{{label}}</th>
      </tr>  
      <tr v-for="item in items">
         <td v-for="label in labels">{{item.label}}</td>
      </tr>  
    </table>  
 </div>
```

My Vue instance looks like this -

```
new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
      labels:[
        'text', 
        'value'
      ],
      items:[ 
        {text: 'One', value: 'A', something:'12'},
        {text: 'Two', value: 'B', something:'67'},
        {text: 'Three', value: 'C', something:'66'}  
      ]  

  }
});
```

This doesn't work because it is attempting to render a variable called 'label' in the declaration `{{item.label}}`. How can I tell it that 'label' is not the literal variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array syntax in Vue.js templates, so the following should work:

```
<td v-for="label in labels">{{ item[label] }}</td>
```